# Which are svg.js use cases and limitations for animation?

Tags: animation, use-case, svg.js

Could you please give some informations about [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) use cases, particularly focusing on animations? For instance:

- environments (browser, export formats, etc...)
- best performances (how to exploit them)
- limitations (how to [not] reach them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

svg.js itself is already quite fast. To give it the optimal performance you might want to conser performant code in general.
That means:

- keep dom manipulation down to a minimum
- cache objects, dont alter thousand of elements at once
  this is especially important when looping
- use latest browsers which all know svg
- and last but not least: Get to know SVG
  because that will give you a feeling which tool is the best for the job